# How to "merge" two URIs in Java?

Tags: java

This is an absolute URI of the server:

```
URI base = new URI("http://localhost/root?a=1");
```

This is a relative URI:

```
URI rel = new URI("/child?b=5");
```

Now I'm trying to apply relative one to the absolute and receive:

```
URI combined = base + rel; // somehow
assert combined.equals(new URI("http://localhost/root/child?a=1&b=5"));
```

Is it possible to do such a manipulation with JDK or some library?

Comment: I'd expect the result to be `http://localhost/child?b=5`, as a relative path beginning with a slash is relative to the host (and even if the slash wasn't there, the "root" bit would be replaced as well as the query string).

Comment: @SimonRichter makes sense, I'm ready to remove the slash, just let me know how to accomplish the merging :)

Comment: What should happen in case of parameter clash, e.g. `root?a=1` and `child?a=5`? `a=1` or `a=5`?

Comment: `URI#resolve()` comes close (`combined = base.resolve(rel)`), but it doesn't combine the query string. I believe this also doesn't really make sense in real world as a query string is normally specific to the original resource. You'd need to do it manually afterwards.

Comment: @BalusC `URI#resolve()` doesn't combine paths, child one will replace the root. The output is `http://localhost/child?b=5`

Comment: @yegor256, the last component is replaced. If /root is a directory, use the canonical `/root/` notation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
URL mergedURL = new URL(new URL(baseUrl), relativeUrl);
```

To pass on base url's parameters to merged url, you'll have to extract them manually by calling URL#getQuery and append them to new URL

Something like,

```
String finalUrl = mergedUrl.toString() + "&" + baseUrl.getQuery();
```

It will take an if() to decide whether an '&' is required to join them depending on what mergedUrl looks like.

Comment: That's effectively what `URI#resolve()` also is doing (and doesn't match OP's requirements, see also comments on the question). Please note that `URI` has a `toURL()` method (and from the other side on, `URL` has a `toURI()` method).

Comment: Actually this method is very close to what I'm looking for. The only problem here is that query params are destroyed in the root, and the output is: `http://localhost/root/child?b=5`

Comment: Really? In my case it omits the `/root` as well.

Comment: @yegor256, If you think a little closely, the 'a' is a parameter to context 'root' and 'b' is a parameter for context 'child'. The relative url will change the context and therefore will not keep any parameters for previous context. If you want to add existing parameters you may extract them by using URL#getQuery() and append them to new URL after merging.

Answer (score 2):

URI (and File also) have a constructor which accepts an existing URI (or File).
It is MADE for relative URI's:
`URL mergedURL = new URL(baseUrl, relativeUrl);`
To merge two File paths you can use:
`File mergedFile = new File(directoryFile, fileOrDir);`
If you use `mergedFile.getName()` you get the filename if it isn't a directory.
This is not possible for an URL.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but works, in this case at least:

```
URI combined = new URI( "http://" + base.getHost() + base.getPath() + rel.getPath() + "?" + base.getQuery() + "&" + rel.getQuery() );
```

The requirement to make the second URL relative to the first, where the first has a query string, is a bit odd.  And the second URL starts with a '/' which implies it's relative to "/", not to "/root"...  are you sure about the resulting URL?

Comment: Indeed.  That's why I had to question the requirements.  This kind of convolution is usually a sign I'm trying to do the wrong thing...

Comment: I tried to come up with something nice, but it resulted in at least two JAR dependencies and ~6 lines of code...